# Error when installing DotNetNuke 5.6.3 using IIS 7.5 and Windows 7

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-settings

I am getting error HTTP handler and MIME type which I never got when i worked on Windows XP and IIS 5.

Please provide steps to configure any ASP.Net application on IIS 7.5 and windows7.

Thanks in advance.

Error screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Please post your exact error message

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.
Please find attached screenshot of the error I am getting. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIS7 does not come with ASP.Net enabled by default.  I suspect you need to enable ASP.Net in IIS.

[How to Install IIS7 and Enable ASP.NET on Windows 7](http://www.gotknowhow.com/articles/how-to-install-iis7-and-enable-aspnet)